# Why is this simple javascript not working?

Tags: javascript, regex

New to js here. Basically I am trying to detect the existence of a string in the present page's url with this:

```
var url = window.location;
var param = /\?provider=/i;
if (url.search(param) != -1) {
    alert('it does exist');
} else
    alert('it does not exist');
```

It works when I manually define the url variable like so

```
var url = 'http://google.com?provider='
```

but when I try to grab it dynamically like in the above script it doesn't work, is there any way to make it work?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want the `href` property on the location object, like this:

```
var url = window.location.href;
var param = /\?provider=/i;
if (url.search(param) != -1) {
    alert('it does exist');
} else
    alert('it does not exist');
```

[`location`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/window.location) isn't a string, it's an object, and doesn't have the [`.search()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/search) method, `.href` is the string that does.

Comment: +1.  You can also do `.toString()` which works on all objects.

Answer (score 0):

`window.location` is an object. Have a look at the entire set of properties of the location object: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/window.location

What you're after is `window.location.href;`